# Django - importing view from Dependency

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls, two-factor-authentication

I'm trying to use [this library](https://github.com/percipient/django-allauth-2fa) since i want to add 2FA Auth to my project. In order to integrate the module in my project, i need to import their views to my **urls.py** file, right?

I tried to import **SetupView**, but i'm getting this error: `module 'allauth_2fa.views' has no attribute 'homepage'`. Here is what i understood: it looks like if i import a view from the dependency, it will only read those views from the dependency **but not** my own views declared on **views.py**.

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.conf.urls import url, include

from django.conf.urls import url

from allauth_2fa import views

app_name = "main"

urlpatterns = [

    path("setup/", views.TwoFactorSetup.as_view(), name="setup"),

    path("", views.homepage, name="homepage"),
    path("register/", views.register, name="register"),
    path("logout/", views.logout_request, name="logout"),
    path("login/", views.login_request, name="login"),

]
```

Extra: **SetupView** will generate the page required to enable the 2FA authentication, that's why i need it. Later i will also import the other views required to have my two factor authentication fully running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you imported

```
from . import views
```

And then:

```
from allauth_2fa import views
```

And after that you tried to do:

```
path("", views.homepage, name="homepage"),
```

And views is allauth_2fa.views not from your project

So you just need to do like this:

```
from allauth_2fa import views as allauth_2fa_views
```

And then use it when you need

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried to change my import to the last line added, but i got this error again: module 'main.views' has no attribute 'TwoFactorSetup'

Comment: TwoFactorSetup is from your project?

Comment: if no just use allauth_2fa_views.TwoFactorSetup instead of views.TwoFactorSetup

Comment: TwoFactorSetup is the view i'm trying to import from the allauth_2fa module

Comment: You should use views when you want to use views from your project and use allauth_2fa_views when you want views from allauth_2fa

Comment: I changed the url to allauth_2fa_views.TwoFactorSetup instead of views.TwoFactorSetup.as_view() and it seems to be working now. Thank you! Just give me 2 minutes to accept your answer